# my js file is not work after i do routing navigate

Tags: jquery, angular

My JavaScript file does not work on angular 4 after I do routing navigate.

1. this is my script file:

   ```
   $(document).on('page:change', function () {
       $('#wsnavtoggle').click(function () {
           $('.wsmenucontainer').toggleClass('wsoffcanvasopener');
           $('.wsmenucontainer').removeClass('wsoffcanvasopener02');
       });
           ....
   });
   ```
2. I include js file on index.html file:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/webslidemenu.js"></script>
   ```
3. at login-page.component.ts , I use routing navigate in login method:

   ```
    login(e) {
    ...
     this.router.navigate(['/main']);
    }
   ```
4. this is my routing:

   ```
   {
         path: 'member',
         component: MemberPageComponent,
         children: [{
                 path: '',
                 redirectTo: 'login',
                 pathMatch: 'full'
             }, {
                 path: 'login',
                 component: LoginPageComponent
             },
             ....
         ]
     },
     {
         path: 'main',
         component: MainPageComponent,
         children: [{
                 path: '',
                 redirectTo: 'trade',
                 pathMatch: 'full'
             }, {
                 path: 'trade',
                 component: TradePageComponent
             },
             ....
         ]
     }
   ```
5. When myapp login successful and navigate to main page, I try to test my script by using slide menu bar, it doesn't work. 
   if I refresh this page, it does work.

I need to make it work after navigate.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: same problem here. Any idea, anyone?